# NSPredicate to arrange NSMutableArray Objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have multiple category list(around 45). i want to show some of the category to first like (Helicopter,Lake Monster,Dinosaur Attack) that will come at the starting after this remaning other will come. i have used the following code.

That works fine. But its to lengthy. so i want to filter this code.

```
NSPredicate *predicate  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", @[@"Helicopter", @"Lake Monster",@"Dinosaur Attack"]];
NSPredicate *predicate1  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"packageName CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"Helicopter"];
NSPredicate *predicate2  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"packageName CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"Lake Monster"];
NSPredicate *predicate3  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"packageName CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"Dinosaur Attack"];

NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSArray *arr1=[packages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate1];
NSArray *arr2=[packages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate2];
NSArray *arr3=[packages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate3];

[filteredArray insertObject:[arr1 objectAtIndex:0] atIndex:0];
[filteredArray insertObject:[arr2 objectAtIndex:0] atIndex:1];
[filteredArray insertObject:[arr3 objectAtIndex:0] atIndex:2];
[packages removeObject:[arr1 objectAtIndex:0]];
[packages removeObject:[arr2 objectAtIndex:0]];
[packages removeObject:[arr3 objectAtIndex:0]];
```

So is there any way to achieve this result with shortest method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cleaning up your own code, you could do the following:

```
NSPredicate *predicate1  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"packageName CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"Helicopter"];
NSPredicate *predicate2  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"packageName CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"Lake Monster"];
NSPredicate *predicate3  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"packageName CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"Dinosaur Attack"];

NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSPredicate *predicate in @[predicate1, predicate2, predicate3]) {
    NSArray *arr=[packages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    [filteredArray addObject:arr[0]];
    [packages removeObject:arr[0]];
}
```

Comment: its pretty gud. but its possible that i could achieve this with only one NSPredicate

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create a class (lets call it STOElement) that has two properties, (NSString*)text, and (NSNumber*)order. Create an instance of that class for each element 'Helicopter' etc, set that as the text, and then set the order you would like that element to appear in as the order (1,2,3 etc).

Then use the `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` to get an array with the order you want

```
NSArray* sortedArray = [arrayOfElements sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(STOElement* element1, STOElement* element2) {
    return [element1.order compare:element2.order];
}];
```